# Tkinter not showing image in Toplevel window while others do

Tags: image, tkinter

I know this has been asked before, but none of the other topics is giving me extra hints on what could be going on. I´ve addad images several times in several windows and toplevel windows, with no problem, but then with this specific one, I´m not getting it to show the picture, I put the exact same code in another toplevel window and it showed the picture... This is the code, it shows the window and all the other widgets too. I checked there are no label frames or some sort that could be covering the image:

```
def valvreggas():
    ventanavalvula = Toplevel()
    ventanavalvula.geometry("1100x400")
    ventanavalvula.title("Gas regulator valve")
    imagevalv = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/gasregulator.png"))
    imgvalvlab = Label(ventanavalvula, image=imagevalv)
    imgvalvlab.place(x=700, y=20)


    # Window widget arrangement

    v1 = Label(ventanavalvula, text="Condición 1", justify="center").place(x=230, y= 30)
    v2 = Label(ventanavalvula, text="Condición 2", justify="center").place(x=360, y= 30)
```

Comment: Where is your mainloop?

Comment: Wow, I missed that, I was so frustated I didn´t even check I missed that window mainloop. Thanks Jordan!!

Comment: You should keep a reference of the image: `imgvalvlab.image = imagevalv`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice acw1668.